# ProcessBuilder call another java file same package

Tags: java, netbeans, path, processbuilder

I am learning how to use **ProcessBuilder**, I created a package called socketspractice, inside I have 2 classes, I am trying to create a new process where 'Program.java' calls 'test1.java' so it prints 'test1'.

When I use command prompt: "java socketspractice.test1" 'test1' prints, but using Netbeans it doesn't.

The question is, how can I set the path so it works the same way or what else am I missing? I am using Netbeans for this.

**Program.java**

```
package socketspractice;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.ProcessBuilder;

public class Program {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    ProcessBuilder builderExecute = new ProcessBuilder("java",  "socketspractice.test1");

    builderExecute.start();

    }
}
```

AND

**test1.java**
    package socketspractice;

```
public class test1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    System.out.println("test1");
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you execute in NetBeans?

Comment: I selected the program file/rmb/run file

Answer (score 0):

The main issue with ur approach is that when you are starting ProcessBuilder it doesnt know where ur project lies on your machine, because its running as a seperate JVM process.

So please create you project as a maven project and then try to put the compiled jar in classpath and then start the process builder.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java","-classpath", 
        "<complete location of your jar containing test1>", "socketspractice.test1")
```